# Не срабатывает обновление из ViewModel при возврате на фрагмент

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, mvvm

Имеется приложение в котором на одном активити в контейнере переключаются три фрагмента. Пытаюсь сохранить некоторые данные в ViewModel и подгрузить их при возврате на фрагмент. Данные при смене фрагмента сохраняются во ViewModel, но почему-то не меняют состояние View-элементов при возврате на этот фрагмент. Интересует MainFragment, т.к. с ним сейчас работаю, функция переключения фрагментов в Extentions.kt. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем заключается моя проблема?

MainActivity:

```
package com.stepa0751.a4relayv2

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.fragments.HomeMaxFragment
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.fragments.MainFragment
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.fragments.SettingsFragment
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.utils.openFragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        onBottomNavClicks()
        openFragment(MainFragment.newInstance())
    }


    private fun onBottomNavClicks(){
        binding.bNav.setOnItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                R.id.id_home -> openFragment(MainFragment.newInstance())
                R.id.id_homemax -> openFragment(HomeMaxFragment.newInstance())
                R.id.id_settings ->openFragment(SettingsFragment())
            }
            true
        }
    }
}
```

MainFragment:

```
package com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.fragments

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.R
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.databinding.FragmentMainBinding
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.models.DataModel
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.models.MainViewModel
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.utils.myLog


class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMainBinding

    lateinit var mViewModel: MainViewModel

    //    private var isServiceRunning = false
    private var id1 = false
    private var id2 = false
    private var id3 = false
    private var id4 = false
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root

    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        myLog("onViewCreated")
        mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        setView()
        setOnClicks()
        onClicks()

    }

    @SuppressLint("FragmentLiveDataObserve")
    fun setView() {
        mViewModel.dataLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
            id1 = it.one
            id2 = it.two
            id3 = it.free
            id4 = it.four
            binding.tvResponse.text = it.string
            myLog("ItString ${it.string}")
            myLog(id4.toString())
        })

    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        myLog("onPause")
        val str = binding.tvResponse.text.toString()
        val strbr1 = binding.br1.text.toString()
        val strbr2 = binding.br1.text.toString()
        val strbr3 = binding.br1.text.toString()
        val strbr4 = binding.br1.text.toString()
        val items = DataModel(id1, id2, id3, id4, str)
        mViewModel.dataLiveData.value = items
    }

    //  Функция инициализации слушателя нажатий для ВСЕГО ВЬЮ
    fun setOnClicks() = with(binding) {
        val listener = onClicks()
        br1.setOnClickListener(listener)
        br2.setOnClickListener(listener)
        br3.setOnClickListener(listener)
        br4.setOnClickListener(listener)
    }

    //  Функция сработки слушателя нажатий на этом вью
    private fun onClicks(): View.OnClickListener {
        return View.OnClickListener {
            when (it.id) {
                R.id.br2 -> startStopService(4)
                R.id.br1 -> startStopService(5)
                R.id.br3 -> startStopService(12)
                R.id.br4 -> startStopService(14)

            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun startStopService(id: Int) {

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)

        if (when (id) {
                4 -> !id1
                5 -> !id2
                12 -> !id3
                14 -> !id4
                else -> {
                    false
                }
            }
        ) {
            val url =
                "http://192.168.1.16/gpio$id/0"
            val sRequest = StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url, { response ->
                    Log.d("MyLog", "All OK! GPIO$id: $response")
                    binding.tvResponse.text = "All OK! GPIO$id: ${
                        response.substringAfter("<html>").substringBefore("<")
                    }"
                },
                {
                    Log.d("MyLog", "Error request0: $it")
                    binding.tvResponse.text = it.toString()
                }
            )
            queue.add(sRequest)
            when (id) {
                4 -> id1 = !id1
                5 -> id2 = !id2
                12 -> id3 = !id3
                14 -> id4 = !id4
                else -> Log.d(
                    "MyLog", "Error request1: $id"
                )
            }
            when (id) {
                4 -> {
                    binding.br2.text =
                        "ON"; binding.br2.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.color_backg_button))
                }

                5 -> {
                    binding.br1.text =
                        "ON"; binding.br1.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.color_backg_button))
                }

                12 -> {
                    binding.br3.text =
                        "ON"; binding.br3.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.color_backg_button))
                }

                14 -> {
                    binding.br4.text =
                        "ON"; binding.br4.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.color_backg_button))
                }

                else -> Log.d("MyLog", "Error request2: $id")
            }

        } else {
            val url =
                "http://192.168.1.16/gpio$id/1"
            val sRequest = StringRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url, { response ->

                    Log.d("MyLog", "All OK! GPIO$id: ${response}")
                    binding.tvResponse.text = "All OK! GPIO$id: ${
                        response.substringAfter("<html>").substringBefore("<")
                    }"
                },
                {
                    Log.d("MyLog", "Error request3: $it")
                    binding.tvResponse.text = it.toString()
                }
            )
            queue.add(sRequest)
            when (id) {
                4 -> id1 = !id1
                5 -> id2 = !id2
                12 -> id3 = !id3
                14 -> id4 = !id4
                else -> {
                    Log.d("MyLog", "Error request4: $id")
                    binding.tvResponse.text = id.toString()
                }
            }
            when (id) {
                4 -> {
                    binding.br2.text =
                        "OFF"; binding.br2.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_tint))
                }

                5 -> {
                    binding.br1.text =
                        "OFF"; binding.br1.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_tint))
                }

                12 -> {
                    binding.br3.text =
                        "OFF"; binding.br3.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_tint))
                }

                14 -> {
                    binding.br4.text =
                        "OFF"; binding.br4.setBackgroundColor(resources.getColor(R.color.background_tint))
                }

                else -> Log.d("MyLog", "Error request5: $id")
            }
        }


    }


    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = MainFragment()
    }
}
```

Extentions.kt:

```
package com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.utils

import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.R

fun Fragment.openFragment(f: Fragment) {
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            android.R.anim.fade_in,
            android.R.anim.fade_out
        ).replace(R.id.placeHolder, f).commit()
}

fun AppCompatActivity.openFragment(f: Fragment) {
        if (supportFragmentManager.fragments.isNotEmpty()){
            if(supportFragmentManager.fragments[0].javaClass == f.javaClass) return
        }
        supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
            android.R.anim.fade_in,
            android.R.anim.fade_out
        ).replace(R.id.placeHolder, f).commit()
    
    }

fun Fragment.showToast(s: String) {
    Toast.makeText(activity, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

fun AppCompatActivity.showToast(s: String) {
    Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

fun Fragment.myLog(v:String){
    Log.d("MyLog", v)
}

fun AppCompatActivity.myLog(v:String){
    Log.d("MyLog", v)
}
```

DataModel:

```
package com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.models

data class DataModel(
 val one:Boolean,
 val two:Boolean,
 val free:Boolean,
 val four:Boolean,
 val string: String,

)
```

MainViewModel:

```
package com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.models

import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class MainViewModel : ViewModel(){

    val dataLiveData = MutableLiveData<DataModel>()
}
```

SecondFragment:

```
package com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.stepa0751.a4relayv2.databinding.FragmentHomeMaxBinding


class HomeMaxFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomeMaxBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentHomeMaxBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() = HomeMaxFragment()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы получаете вью-модель у провайдера, привязанного к самому фрагменту:

```kotlin
mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Поэтому модель уничтожается вместе с фрагментом.
Отдельный вопрос: не лучше ли кэшировать фрагменты при переключении?...
Так же можно указать хранилищем моделей активность - тогда они будут живы, пока жива активность:

```kotlin
mViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())mViewModel.get(MainViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за Ваш ответ. Действительно помогло изменение хранилища моделей на активити. До кэширования обязательно доберусь, но позже - я только учусь. А т.к. я самоучка в свои 40 лет, то не все дается сразу. Еще раз благодарю за то, что откликнулись.  С Уважением.